# What does Cross origin requests mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a js application that detects single, double right, double left clicks etc. Single click is for  async. request http server and rest are to change user interface on client side.
But I cannot succeed to send the request to the server and see error on client side.
Nothing is sent, I read it from my web server's log.

those are the error messages on console:

```
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:5050/h?timestampDate=2010-undefined-null&timestampHour=null. 
   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.   
   send ([native code], line 0)
   h (tm, line 420)
   (anonymous function) (tm, line 72)

[Error] NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occurred in synchronous requests.
   h (tm, line 420)
   (anonymous function) (tm, line 72)
```

What is the problem here. What does Cross origin requests mean. What is the difference here in my ajax request from the previous one ı could do successfully.

Note: in fiddle first error reference (tm, line 420) is on line 344 of js, second is on line 11 of js.

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/farukscan/6kUBy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is stemming from the URL string:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "localhost:5050/h" + "?" + ..., true);
```

When including a host, you'll want to prefix it with at least `//` so the browser knows the string is an absolute URL:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "//localhost:5050/h" + "?" + ..., true);
//                   ^^
```

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:5050/h" + "?" + ..., true);
```

Otherwise, the URL is assumed to be relative to the current page's address, so the browser is attempting to treat `localhost:5050` as a folder name.

---

And, "Cross Origin" refers to URLs which fail the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This is a security restriction on the addresses client-side JavaScript can access.

The "Origin" is a combination of the protocol, hostname, and port from the current address.

Comment: in my case what I hould have done to solve problem was to use only the name of the function on server as "/h" ... I haven't the intention to make cross origin request already. thanks. that again answers it and others.